# Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition, 1-ый запуск, фактически Hello, World!

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace hello
{
   class main
    {
       static public int Main()
       {
           double x;
           x = 23.5;
           x = x + 1;
           return 0;
       }

    }
}
```

в том что это компилится, я не сомневаюсь, но как увидеть результат, может паузу как-то поставить, в output сплошная каша?

Comment: в C# можно в конце каждой ф-ии `return 0` не пихать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того что бы консоль не закрывалась нужно в конце функции вызвать метод

***[Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.read) - Читает следующий символ из стандартного входного потока.***

или

***[Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readkey) - считает символ.***

Разница между ними в том что первый считает любой символ, т.е. программа не закроется пока не будет нажат любой символ, а второй считает клавишу которую можно будет отловить потом программно.

По поводу return, это далеко не С++ и здесь его ставить без необходимости. Ваш пример должен выглядеть так:

```
static void Main()
       {
           double x;
           x = 23.5;
           x = x + 1;
           Console.WriteLine(x);
           Console.Read();
       }
```

Собственно считать символ можно через метод

***[Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline) - Считывает следующую строку символов из стандартного входного потока.***

Желаю удачи в изучении C#!

Comment: @johniek_comp все правильно написал, одно вещь скажу:return необходимо указывать в том случае когда объявляете функцию с каким то типом(кроме void).

Answer (score 3):

лучше бы ты хело ворд написал, это не ету фигню...
добавь в конце. перед ретурном

```
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, в книге пока об этом ничего не сказано. (О том как hello world вывести), такое вот начало...

Comment: "(50 секунд назад)" Обогнали :)
А если в книге дают пример без Console.ReadKey(); или Console.ReadLine(); , то это какая-то плохая книга.